# Nginx reverse proxy (in Docker) to a web app (also in Docker)

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have set up a web application in docker which is currently running internal to the host at 172.19.0.3:8888. I want this web application accessible over the internet on port 443 (https), with requests to port 80 (HTTP) redirected to 443.

I plan to use an Nginx reverse proxy in a docker container to achieve this, but I do not know how to properly configure it to point at the docker container 172.19.0.3:8888. Accessing http://172.19.0.3:8888 from the host works.

Here is the guide I tried to follow, but it just didn't show how to point at a docker container specifically.

https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

## Note

If I set the port 443 proxy_pass to http://example.org, it works. So Cert configurations are working correctly.

## Web application

Running on 172.19.0.3:8888 internal to the host

## docker-compose for Nginx and Certbot

My certs are coming back clean.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./Volumes/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./Volumes/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./Volumes/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./Volumes/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./Volumes/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```

## Nginx app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name forums.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
}

    location / {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }    
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name forums.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/forums.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/forums.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.19.0.3:8888/;
    }
}
```

## Web Application

```
  flarum:
    image: mondedie/docker-flarum:0.1.0-beta.8.1-stable
    container_name: flarum
    env_file:
      - ./flarum.env
    volumes:
      - ./Volumes/assets:/flarum/app/public/assets
      - ./Volumes/extensions:/flarum/app/extensions
      - ./Volumes/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=flarum
      - MYSQL_USER=flarum
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./Volumes/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose creates a seprate network for `docker-compose.yaml` file.

So you can add your web application as service (eg: webapp) in current compose file. And in `nginx.conf` directly point to your service. Rather than using IP you can use the service name as DNS which will resolve by Docker for the same network.

```
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp:8888/;
    }
```

Comment: I attached my docker compose for the webapp. The service name is 'flarum'. Changing proxy_pass to http://flarum:8888/ did not work. I attempted this before i posted :(

Comment: all your service nginx, certbot, mariadb and flarum are in same `docker-compose.yaml` right?

Comment: For debugging try to ping your service from nginx container `ping flarum`